# Copy-SPSite : Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

I'm using Copy-SPSite to duplicate a site collection.

```
Copy-SPSite http://mysite.com/dept/01 -TargetUrl http://mysite.com/dept/02 -DestinationDatabase WSS_Content
```

/dept is a managed path. But I got this error:

```
Copy-SPSite : Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
At line:1 char:1
+ Copy-SPSite http://mysite.com/dept/01 -TargetUrl
http ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...PCmdletCopySite:
   SPCmdletCopySite) [Copy-SPSite], SPException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletCopySite
```

If there is no managed path, then it works fine, i.e.

```
Copy-SPSite http://mysite.com/01 -TargetUrl http://mysite.com/02 -DestinationDatabase WSS_Content
```

My question is: how to use Copy-SPSite for managed path?

Thanks

update:
I noticed that, for some reasons, only /dept/01 has this issue. some other site collections do not as long as the managed path is Explicit inclusion. The question is: what can cause this? is it some objects in the site collection? since /dept/01 exists, why do not just duplicate it even it has some issues. weird.*

Comment: are you making the copy into same content db?

Comment: one more thing, do you have the site collection /dept/02 or not? if yes delete it, if not then remove the destination database paramter and rerun the command....one more thing run this command get-spsite http:///mysite.com/dept/01, share the result

Comment: yes, in the same content database. should it be in different one? get-spsite shows /dept/01 url and compatibilityLevel: 15.

Comment: really it does not matter, just remove the database switch and run again, also check ULS logs may be get more clue...this command is very much straight fwd, make a copy within same web application.

Comment: have you ever created a site collection on this path /dept/02 and deleted it?

Comment: not use database switch, same error. it did not have /dept/02, same error. then I manually created /dept/02 and /test (just for testing), same error.

Comment: did you try to use different name i.e dept/03 or 04....if still failing....then you can use the old fashioned method bakup site and resotre-spsite

Comment: same error. weird thing is: store-spsite has the erro: <nativehr>0x80070003<nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>....[Restore-SPSite], DirectoryNotFoundException.....

Comment: what command you are using.....can you try to test on different site collection..i mean backup of different site collectio instead of /dept/01 to some other sites.

Comment: I backup site collection /dept/01, then use: Restore-SPSite http://mysite.com/dept/02 -Path C:\SPBackup\dept01.bak